# Django - Unable to pass page title as url parameter in template

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I have a BIG problem.
I need to pass article title to URL in the template

**This is my urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    ***
    re_path(r'^view/(?P<id>\w+)/(?P<title>\w+)/$', views.view, name='view'),
    ***
]
```

**view.py**

```
def view(request, id, title):
    return render(request, 'view.html', {'id' : id, 'title' : title})
```

**At first I tried**

```
<a href="{% url 'view' id=3685 title='What a terrible weather' %}">What a terrible weather</a>
```

**And I got that error message:**

```
NoReverseMatch at /view/7/6999/
Reverse for 'view' with keyword arguments '{'id': 3685, 'title': 'What a terrible weather'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['view/(?P<id>\\w+)/(?P<title>\\w+)/$']
*** 
Error during template rendering
In template D:\Django\gtunews\templates\view.html, error at line 8 Reverse for 'view' with keyword arguments '{'id': 3685, 'title': 'What a terrible weather'}' not found. 
1 pattern(s) tried: ['view/(?P<id>\\w+)/(?P<title>\\w+)/$']
***
```

**Then I tried**

```
{% with thevarable= "What a terrible weather" %}     
    <a href="{% url 'view' id=3685 title=thevarable %}">What a terrible weather</a>
{% endwith %}
```

**The result:**

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /view/7/6999/
'with' expected at least one variable assignment
***
Error during template rendering
In template D:\Django\gtunews\templates\view.html, error at line 8
'with' expected at least one variable assignment
***
```

**Also I tried**

```
{% with my_var = 'What a terrible weather'.replace(' ','_') %}
    <div>Hello, {{my_var}}!</div>
{% endwith %}
```

**As a result I go the same error:**

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /view/7/6999/
'with' expected at least one variable assignment
***
Error during template rendering
In template D:\Django\gtunews\templates\view.html, error at line 8
'with' expected at least one variable assignment
***
```

**Then I tried**

```
{{ title|urlencode:"What a terrible weather" }}
```

Result: To my surprise it returned **ID** instead of **Title**

I tried that too. And It's the only possible way it works. It only works if we pass a single word as parameter **BUT** Who need it? It's a nonsense form.

```
<a href="{% url 'view' id=3685 title='idontneedtopassanparameterlikethat' %}">idontneedtopassanparameterlikethat</a>
```

As I can see on my clock, I waisted four hours to in searching a solution which I couldn't found And in conclution I think this maybe my last project on Django framework.
Time is more expensive than money. I even spent a lot of time on the Django Framework and even got bored.

Please, help me to find a answer.

Comment: I think, you are using those versions which is no longer supported now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a string on path

`path('view/<int:id>/<str:title>/', views.view, name='view'),`